# pyusb reading operation always return '1'

Tags: python-3.x, pyusb

I'm trying to create USB driver object using pyusb for my code, and the return from reading operation always return '1', I search the web for a while, and I couldn't find any solution, please try to help me understand what am I'm doing wrong.

Environmental properties:
Using python 3.7 with pycharm on windows 10.
Imported all necessary packages (usb.core, usb.util) of course after installing the pyusb module.

The object I'm trying to build:

```
class UsbDev:
    def __init__(self, VID, PID):
        self.output_ep = None
        self.input_ep = None
        self.VID = VID
        self.PID = PID
        self.dev = usb.core.find(idVendor = self.VID, idProduct = self.PID)
        if self.dev is None:
            raise AttributeError('USB device is not connected...')

    def check_device(self, dev_name=None):
        if dev_name is None:
            raise ValueError("device name provided is None")
        if self.dev.product != dev_name:
            raise ValueError('Wrong type of product connected to host')

    def config_device(self):
        self.dev.set_configuration()
        cfg = self.dev.get_active_configuration()
        self.output_ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(cfg[(0, 0)], custom_match=lambda e:
            usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)
        self.input_ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(cfg[(0, 0)], custom_match=lambda e:
            usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN)

    def read_string(self):
        if self.input_ep is not None:
            ret_array = self.dev.read(self.input_ep.bEndpointAddress,
                                      self.input_ep.wMaxPacketSize)
            self.dev.clear_halt(self.input_ep)
            return ''.join([chr(x) for x in ret_array])  # always returns 1
```

the test case:

```
driver = ud(0x0403, 0xed72)  # HAMEG HO720 Serial Port
driver.check_device('HAMEG HO720')
driver.config_device()
driver.send("*IDN?")    
print(driver.read_string())
```

expected output:

> HAMEG,HMP4040,055310003,HW50020001/SW2.41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I've solved the problem myself.
It appears that some USB devices require a termination character (in my case it was newline char '\n') so upon sending a message with newline the device started to reply.

I hope that my case helps you guys.